# How do I create an .ics event with a title using ri_cal

Tags: ruby, icalendar

I'm using the `ri_cal` gem to create ics files. The gem's documentation suggests I do this:

```
RiCal.Calendar do |cal|
  cal.event do |event|
    event.description = "MA-6 First US Manned Spaceflight"
    event.dtstart =  DateTime.parse("2/20/1962 14:47:39")
    event.dtend = DateTime.parse("2/20/1962 19:43:02")
    event.location = "Cape Canaveral"
    event.add_attendee "john.glenn@nasa.gov"
    event.alarm do
      description "Segment 51"
    end
  end
end
```

But when I open the .ics file this creates in OS X Calendar, the event has no title. Only the Description has been set as described.

How do I set the event's title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.summary`:

```
RiCal.Calendar do |cal|
  cal.event do |event|
    event.summary = "The 'title' of the event"
    event.description = "MA-6 First US Manned Spaceflight"
    event.dtstart =  DateTime.parse("2/20/1962 14:47:39")
    event.dtend = DateTime.parse("2/20/1962 19:43:02")
    event.location = "Cape Canaveral"
    event.add_attendee "john.glenn@nasa.gov"
    event.alarm do
      description "Segment 51"
    end
  end
end
```

[ri_cal/properties/event.rb](https://github.com/rubyredrick/ri_cal/blob/master/lib/ri_cal/properties/event.rb) has a full list of properties you can set.